# What is the baseline in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

What does "baseline" refer to when used in the context of a relative layout? Simple question, probably, but the documentation and google offer no hints.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The term [baseline comes from typography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29). It's the invisible line letters in text sit on.

For example, imagine you put two `TextView` elements next to each other. You give the second `TextView` a big padding (say 20dp). If you add `layout_alignBaseline` to the second element, the text will "scoot up" to align with the baseline of the first element. The text from both elements will appear as if they were written on the same invisible line.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:text="aatlg"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
  <TextView
      android:text="joof"
      android:background="#00ff00"
      android:padding="20dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/text1"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Adding an explanatory image would be great

Comment: Also It's true by default

Answer (score 37):

Here is a visual explanation that might clarify Cristian's answer:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Lorem"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ipsum"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/text1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This code will look like this:

[image: with android:layout_alignBaseline]

Now, if I remove the `android:layout_alignBaseline` attribute, the same layout looks like this:[image: without android:layout_alignBaseline]

It's interesting to observe that there is an impact on the orange view's height (in the first case the padding is *not* applied to the top of the view).