# XML Android diferences between "end edge", "right edge", "toEndOf", "toRightOf"

Tags: android-layout

At .xml Android Studio, what are the differences between:

1) "**end edge**" and "**right edge**" ?

2) "**toEndOf**" and "**toRightOf**" ?

3) "**start edge**" and "**left edge**" ?

4) "**alignBaseline**" and "**alignBottom**" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything with a direction assigned to it is literal, as in left will always be left, right will always be right. Start and End are dependent on whether a language reads left-to-right or right-to-left, start and end matching those accordingly.

alignBaseline will align to the bottom of the text itself, where alignBottom will align to the bottom of the view. So in a view with text that has 10dp padding under it, alignBottom will align 10dp below the text, where alignBaseline will align with the bottom of the text itself.

This post has a good explanation of baseline.
[What is the baseline in RelativeLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447361/what-is-the-baseline-in-relativelayout)

Comment: Thanks! I also found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24541992/684582